# Rules to convert a CFG to a NDPA?

Tags: parsing, grammar, dfa, nfa

I have to define an FA by using this grammar:

```
S -> aSb
S -> c
S -> dA
A -> Sd
```

How do I manage the first rule and the last one?
For the second one I think I have to create another state (the final one) and link S and this new state. For the third one instead, I think I have to create the state "A" and link it to S by passing "d".

Comment: The title of your question indicates that you have a LLG, but you certainly do not. What are you asking? Are you asking how to make a finite automata for that grammar? That grammar isn't regular.

Comment: Hello, I though this was a left linear grammar because of the last rule. How do I proceed to create the FA?

Comment: No a LLG is one in which _all_ rules, not just one, have a single nonterminal on the left. You cannot create an FA with this grammar. The grammar is not regular (because of the first rule). No FA exists. You can make an NDPA though because the language is definitely context-free. Where did you get this problem?

Comment: If I would create an NDPA, which rules should I follow?

Comment: You can find dozens of tutorials and examples online. I just googled "how to make an NPDA from a CFG" and got quite a few hits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are algorithms you can use to get a PDA from a CFG: look into top-down and bottom-up parsers, for instance. What I think of as the usual proof that PDAs accept languages generated by CFGs, and vice versa, uses such a construction.

An alternative is to understand the language generated by the grammar, and to design a PDA for it directly. This is less mechanical but has the potential to yield a more concise PDA. If you want to go this route, we can first simplify the grammar by recognizing the nonterminal A can safely be replaced by the RHS of the only production for it:

```
S -> aSb
S -> c
S -> dSd    // removed A -> Sd and replaced here
```

How does this grammar work?

1. You have `c` in the middle by the 2nd production;
2. You have matching `d`s on the left and right of the `c`;
3. You have `a`s on the left matching `b`s on the right of `c`.

A PDA should work as follows:

1. Read `a`s and `d`s until you see a `c`. Push everything on the stack as you go. When you see a `c`, go to the next state, but don't push the `c`.
2. Read `b`s and `d`s, popping `a`s and `d`s from the stack, until:

   - The topmost stack symbol doesn't match input; crash.
   - You run out of input with symbols still on the stack; crash.
   - You run out of stack symbols with input remaining; crash.
   - You run out of stack and input simultaneously; accept.

Here's a transition table:

```
q    s      x    q'   s'
------------------------------
q0   a,d,Z  a    q0   aa,ad,aZ
q0   a,d,Z  d    q0   da,dd,dZ
q0   a,d,Z  c    q1   a,d,Z
q1   a      b    q1   -
q1   d      d    q1   -
```

If we accept in q1 by empty stack, these transitions are enough. If we want to accept by empty stack or accepting state, we could add a transition like `f(q1, Z, -) = (q2, Z)` and make `q2` accepting; the PDA would transition there nondeterministically and would crash unless the input were also exhausted.